# opções no input com html

Tags: javascript, html, select, input, option

no html existe uma propiedade chamada **SELECT** e tambem o **INPUT** e eu gostaria de fazer um **INPUT** com opções igual ao **SELECT** porem como posso fazer isso? o código que utilizei:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
      <head>
        <title>só um teste</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      </head>
        <input type="text" placeholder="sua faixa etária">
          <option value="">faixa etária:</option>
          <option value="-18">menor de idade</option>
          <option value="+18">maior de idade</option>
          <option value="+60">idoso</option>
        </input>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: pesquise: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp.

Comment: obrigado! achei um atributo chamado datalist com exatamente o que eu quiria fazer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o atributo [`list`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#list) do elemento `<input type="text">` em conjunto do elemento [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist). O elemento `<datalist>` é um container de elementos `[<option>][2]` que representam as possíveis opções de valor de outros controles. Por sua vez a propriedade `list` indica a lista de opções adotada pelo controle.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>só um teste</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="sua faixa etária" list="faixa">
  <datalist id="faixa">
    <option value="">faixa etária:</option>
    <option value="-18">menor de idade</option>
    <option value="+18">maior de idade</option>
    <option value="+60">idoso</option>
  </datalist>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muito obrigado!